# I want to make a service in android but my service not running?

Tags: java, android, service

my app install but when reboot device not running.

my service:

```
package com.example.service_m;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ServiceCode extends Service{

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
      @Override
      public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //TODO do something useful

          for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello world", 
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }

        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
      }

}
```

my BroadcastReceiver:

```
package com.example.service_m;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ServiceStarter extends BroadcastReceiver{

     @Override
        public void onReceive(Context _context, Intent _intent) {

           Intent service = new Intent(_context, ServiceCode.class );
           _context.startService(service);
        }


}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.service_m.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
                <receiver android:name="com.example.service_m.ServiceStarter" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
            <service
    android:name="com.example.service_m.ServiceCode.class">
    </service>
    </application>
```

my app install but not running when device reboot.
what is problem?
please help me!
I want to learn make a background app.

Comment: Why your doing the task under onStartCommand? just simple override the onCreate method and do what ever you want in this method.

Comment: You don't have your Service listed in the manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define the service & permission in your manifest file

```
    <service
        android:name="com.example.service_m.ServiceCode">
    </service>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Use this code in the your receiver :

```
 Intent service = new Intent(_context, ServiceCode.class );
   _context.startService(service);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
<service
android:name="com.example.service_m.ServiceCode.class">
</service>
```

I think it should be below (remove .class)

```
<service
android:name="com.example.service_m.ServiceCode">
</service>
```

Comment: Why do you use com.example.service_m.ServiceCode.class?

Answer (score 0):

Very close, but a couple of things you missed:

First and foremost the permission needs to be in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Second, define your service in the manifest:

```
<service
    android:name="com.example.service_m.ServiceCode"
    android:exported="false"
    android:label="ServiceCode" />
```

Also you might need enabled on the receiver:

```
android:enabled="true"
```

One last thing, try logging instead of toast for your debug, usually a bit more useful :)

```
Log.i("Service Starter", "Hello WOrld");
```

Hope that helps.